# RMI tutorial errors with ComputeEngine

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

So I've spent quite awhile trying to find an answer from other people having trouble with the RMI tutorial, but I'm completely stumped on this. I'm doing this tutorial through eclipse.

My ComputeEngine Class. This is just copied from the tutorial, so I don't think there's anything wrong with it.

```
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import compute.Compute;
import compute.Task;

public class ComputeEngine implements Compute {

    public ComputeEngine() {
        super();
    }

    public <T> T executeTask(Task<T> t) {
        return t.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        }
        try {
            String name = "Compute";
            Compute engine = new ComputeEngine();
            Compute stub = (Compute) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0);
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.rebind(name, stub);
            System.out.println("ComputeEngine bound");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("ComputeEngine exception:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I start the rmiregistry in the command line with

```
set classpath=
start rmiregistry
```

My VM arguments in eclipse are:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/C:/Users/Kevin/workspace/RMI/bin/
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=Compute
-Djava.security.policy=server.policy
```

I have the compute.jar file and the the server.policy files in the bin folder. I granted all permissions for the policy file.

```
grant{
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

After all that, I run ComputeEngine and get the following errors:

```
ComputeEngine exception:
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission          127.0.0.1:1099 connect,resolve)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
at engine.ComputeEngine.main(ComputeEngine.java:31)
```

It seems like it has some kind of problem with rebind, but I don't understand what. I also don't understand the AccessControlException, when I have the policy file. I've checked to make sure the rmiregistry is still running, and I don't close the empty window that comes up after starting it.

So yeah, I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly your security policy file isn't being *found.* It would need to be in the current working directory when you execute the program. Run your program with -Djava.security.debug=access,failure to see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

The exception clearly says that your code base does not have permission to creat sockets/ for network communication. The reason could be with your security policy specification alone. Do not specify the policy file explicitly and allow the JVM to use the default security policy. The default policy specifies the right permissions so you should be fine.

Comment: How could it be a problem with his 'security specification alone' when it specifies AllPermission?

Comment: Your policy file may not be referred at all. You only mention the file name and not the complete path. So whether the file will be referred will really depend on how and from where you launch your program. Either you dont specify the policy at all so that the JVM refers the default policy file or mention the complete path to the file.